# Confusion on work done in reversible and irreversible process and others

Tags: thermodynamics, work, reversibility

I am greatly confused with the following things

1. Work done in reversible and irreversible process

Here: Since first law is only the energy conservation, if you have a gas, closed with a movable piston ( no friction ) , the work done in reversible or irreversible is the product of external pressure times the change in volume, irrespective of reversibility. Because this way, you also consider how external elements are changing the gas. Is this true ?

2. Given a process, how exactly would you say whether it reversible, irreversible or quasi-static or not ? Say for example, if it given that due to constant external pressure the gas is compressed rapidly, how exactly would you classify into the above classes ?

Comment: The answer to question 1 is "yes."  With regard to question 2, if the gas is compressed rapidly, the process would be considered irreversible.  To be considered reversible, it would have to be compressed slowly enough, such that the gas never deviates more than a slight amount from being in thermodynamic equilibrium throughout the entire compression.

Comment: For a better understanding of the reason for the difference in work between reversible and irreversible compression and expansion thermodynamic processes, see the following:  https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/reversible-vs-irreversible-gas-compressionexpansion-work/